# SVM implementation using cvxpy

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, cvxpy

I am implementing soft margin svm with cvxpy. I keep getting the error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. But i don't understand where this error is from.

This code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvxpy as cp
from cvxpy import *
   
np.random.seed(6201)
mean1 = [-1, -1]
mean2 = [1, 1]
cov = [[1, 0.25], [0.25, 1]]
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov, 200)
y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov, 200)

#plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],color='blue')
#plt.scatter(y[:,0],y[:,1],color='red')


print(x.shape)
m = x.shape[0]
n = x.shape[1]

w = cp.Variable((n, 1))
b = cp.Variable()
xi = cp.Variable((m, 1))
print(w.shape)
print(b.shape)
print(y.shape)

objective = cp.Minimize(1/2*cp.square(cp.norm(w))+ C * cp.sum(xi))
constraints=[cp.matmul(y, (np.dot(x,w) + b)) + xi >=1, xi>=0 ] 
prob = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
result = prob.solve()
```

Gives error

```
---> 64 constraints=[cp.matmul(y, (np.dot(x,w) + b)) + xi >=1, xi>=0 ]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can anyone show me what to do to fix the problem in the above code above so that it stops throwing this error message?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your `y` is meant to have a size of `(200,2)`?

The other thing is, I'm not sure `np.dot(x, w)` works in this case. Try using the `@` operator, or `cp.matmul`.

I changed `y = y[:, 0]` and `np.dot(x,w)` -> `x @ w` and it can fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
constraints = [np.matmul(D, (x @ w.T + b * e) + xi) >= e]
```

`D` is the diagonal matrix of y and e is a matrix of ones of shape `(m,1)`.